# Struts 2 action not working if the action name is "apply"

Tags: java, struts2, http-status-code-404, actionresult, xml-configuration

Problem so simple, if the action name is `apply`
this action doesn't work at all, and it gave the

```
HTTP Status 404 - No result defined for action com.control.actions.ClassName and result success
```

Example of the `struts.xml`:

```
<action name="apply" method="display"
    class="com.control.actions.ClassName">
    <result name="none">/page.jsp</result>
</action>
```

but it works if the action name is anything else
like:

```
<action name="applying" method="display"
    class="com.control.actions.ClassName">
    <result name="none">/page.jsp</result>
</action>
```

So is `apply` a kind of Struts2 keyword?

Comment: where you have defined your result/jsp for success result? error is saying same thing

Comment: No, apply isn't a keyword. You haven't given enough information to really help you though.

Answer (score 0):

> No, *apply* isn't a keyword.

The error message tells that no result defined is `success` for the action.

In most cases this means that no result is configured for the action. If you are using convention or rest plugins there may be implicit configs created using conventions.

Use the [config-browser](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/config-browser) plugin to see the configuration *provided* to your application or debug to troubleshoot it.